# Repository save method returns entity with some null fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I send a request with a body:

```json
{
  "name"        : "French fries",
  "ingredients" : [
                    {
                       "id" : 1
                    }
                  ]

}
```

And receive:

```json
{
  "id"          : 1, 
  "name"        : "French fries", 
  "ingredients" : [
                    {
                      "id"   : 1,
                      "name" : null
                    }
                  ]

}
```

The id references an ingredient that already exists:

````json
{
  "id"   : 1,
  "name" : "potato"
}
```.
<br/>As you can see, the name of the ingredient in null.
Here's my model:
```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "dishes")
@Data
public class Dish {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonView(Views.Full.class)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @JsonView(Views.Partial.class)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "dish_ingredients",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dish_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id"))
    @JsonView(Views.Partial.class)
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();}
````

```java
@Data
@Table(name = "ingredients")
@Entity
public class Ingredient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonView({Views.Full.class, Views.Partial.class})
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private String name;
}
```

Here's what I do in service:

```
public Dish createDish(Dish dish) {
    return dishRepository.saveAndFlush(dish);
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("dishes")
public Dish createDish(@RequestBody @JsonView(Views.Partial.class) Dish dish) {
    return itemService.createDish(dish);
}
```

Comment: can you also host the JSON payload you are sending?

Comment: @Shiva , I have it in my question, but here it is again: {"name": "French fries", "ingredients": [{"id": 1}]}(If I understood what u were asking for.

Comment: I think it works perfectly. You get back the object you just sent. (the ingredient is just a reference) If you want to send back the whole object then you need to load it back from the DB eagerly after the save.

Comment: @Selindek, could you please tell me the right way to load the whole object from the db?

Comment: The only solution I had come up with was to get other fields from other repositories.

Comment: The simplest solution is if you set the ingredients properly to load eagerly. (It's NOT recommended if you don't need those properties usually). The other solution if you create a unique getBy or findBy repository method and annotate it with @EntityGraph, where you can set which properties should be loaded eagerly. Then  you simply call this method after the successful save.